# How to count rows having column entries equal to a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
    SYMBOL FinalCall.x FinalCall.y
    A1BG           2           2
 A1BG-AS           2           2
    A1CF           2           1
   A2LD1           1           1
     A2M           1           1
   A2ML1           2           2
```

How to count rows in data frame having both column elements equal to 1 or equal to 2

**Update:**

Output

Considering both columns contain `1` the count should be `two`

```
         A2LD1         1           1
         A2M           1           1
```

If looked for `2` then count of rows should be `three`

```
     A1BG            2           2
     A1BG-AS         2           2
     A2ML1           2           2
```

Comment: `table(rowSums(mydf[-1] == 2) == 2)`? What's the output you're looking for?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Kindly check updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can use a combination of `==` and `rowSums`, something like this:

```
mydf[rowSums(mydf[-1] == 2) == 2, ]
#    SYMBOL FinalCall.x FinalCall.y
# 1    A1BG           2           2
# 2 A1BG-AS           2           2
# 6   A2ML1           2           2

mydf[rowSums(mydf[-1] == 1) == 2, ]
#   SYMBOL FinalCall.x FinalCall.y
# 4  A2LD1           1           1
# 5    A2M           1           1
```

The basic idea is to:

- Exclude the first column (`mydf[-1]`)
- Check for the value you're interested in (`== 1`, `== 2`, for example)
- Use `rowSums` to see if, by row, there are the same number of `TRUE` values as there are columns.